# gcp - no concurrent builds quota available to create builds

Tags: windows-10, cloud, google-cloud-platform

in Google Cloud i am trying to import a Win10 vmdk from my Bucket via the "google cloud SDK" and am receiving following error:

> C:\Users\olli\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute instances
> import win10pro1263512 --os=windows-10-x64-byol
> --source-uri="gs://win10-20220328/win10pro.ova"
>
> WARNING: Importing OVF. This may take 40 minutes for smaller OVFs and
> up to a couple of hours for larger OVFs.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.import) FAILED_PRECONDITION:
> generic::failed_precondition: no concurrent builds quota available to
> create builds

I am following these procedures: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NG38am3Y8hM&t=461s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI-f8P0Rn8Y

Then i tried following (found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9briGXNRpI&t=271s):

Open Cloud-Shell, then type:

> gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com
>
> gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-id \    --member
> serviceAccount:project-num@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \    --role
> roles/compute.admin
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-id \    --member
> serviceAccount:project-num@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \    --role
> roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-id \    --member
> serviceAccount:project-num@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \    --role
> roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator

*Replaced "project-num" and  my "project-id" with my values.

Then:
gcloud compute instances import win10pro 
--os=windows-10-x64-byol 
--zone europe-west3-c 
--source-uri=gs://win10-20220328/win10pro.ova

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.import) FAILED_PRECONDITION:
> generic::failed_precondition: no concurrent builds quota available to
> create builds

Could you please help me?
I searched but cannot find any help for this message.

My Quota:

Cloud Build API     Concurrent builds                                                 **10**

Cloud Build API     Concurrent builds per Worker Pool    region : europe-west3         **2**

Cloud Build API     Private Pools per region             region : europe-west3
**1**

Kind Regards,
Olli

---

yes billing seems to be enabled. I am charged monthly.
This is my status:

> C:\Users\olli\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud beta billing
> projects describe exxxxxxxx610 billingAccountName:
> billingAccounts/01XXXX-11111-ZZZZZ billingEnabled: true name:
> projects/exxxxxxxx610/billingInfo projectId: exxxxxxxx610
>
> C:\Users\olli\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>

(*changed/obsfucated my values...)

Comment: Do you have billing enabled?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue as well. I found that for some reason GCP restricted the regions that my project was allowed to use Cloud Build in.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/locations#restricted_regions_for_some_projects

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1135378)

Comment: This solved the issue for me, I had to build to europe-west1 instead of europe-central2 to get it working